# jqGrid passing extra parameters when calling delGridRow

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I was reading the documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) regarding how delete row API works,
but I didn't find any way to cleanly pass down extra parameter/s. Its possible in edit and also when fetching data, but not with delete.

Basically to explain why I need it, I have session based editable grid, but session needs a unique guid which is generated when rows are written into session, then i render them as hidden inputs(outside of grid) with specific id so that each grid knows which input is his.
I know that gridDelRow has "url" option and I could concatenate the url with query string, but then it would break my current behavior for controller action method which looks currently like this

```
public virtual ActionResult EditRow(RowGridViewModel rowGridViewModel, string guid)
{
        return HandleGridItemEdit(rowGridViewModel, guid);
}
```

And this is my jqGrid API call

```
$(gridObject).jqGrid("delGridRow", id, {
    "top": "",
    "left": "",
    "width": "150px",
    "zIndex": 99999,
    "modal": true,
    "drag": false,
    "closeOnEscape": true,
});
```

So if I edit url option it breaks my current functionality, which is not an option as the same method for edit of the row is used.
Also I know that I could render hidden columns with this data inside, but this is really ugly. So if you have any suggestions how this would be done I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
function deleteRow(id, gridObject) {
    var gridGuid = getGridSessionGuid(gridObject);
    $(gridObject).jqGrid("delGridRow", id, { "delData": { guid: gridGuid } });
}
```

**EDIT:** Ups didn't see the comments

Comment: Well since I can't accept @Olegs comment as an answer I'll accept yours and its still a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a decent solution, which doesn't break my code I just have to take care that all action methods have the same name of the parameter "rowGridViewModel".

```
    function deleteRow(id, gridObject) {
        var gridGuid = getGridSessionGuid(gridObject);
        $(gridObject).jqGrid("delGridRow", id, {
            "serializeDelData": function (postdata) {
                return { rowGridViewModel: postdata, guid: gridGuid };
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can use `delData: {guid: gridGuid}` option of `delGridRow` to extend the data posted by `delGridRow`.

Comment: Wow thanks how the hell did I miss that one... Now I see it in documentation. And its better solution than mine.